# Masked url doesn't display images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following condition and rule in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^simulator/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ simulator/$1 [L]
```

It will rewrite everything to the `simulator` folder and also will mask the url, such as `simulator` doesn't show in the address bar.

However, although images are properly rewritten, they show as broken.

**Why is that** if the condition and rewrite should catch everything.

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` will always start with a slash, so the _CondPattern_ should be `!^/simulator/` (not `!^simulator/`) - otherwise it will never match and will _always_ rewrite (but this would have resulted in a rewrite loop?). How do you know the images are properly rewritten? If they are rewritten to an image on the filesystem then it should not be "broken"?

Comment: @w3d The image location is rendered as `example.org/images/01.jpg` instead of `example.org/simulator/images/01.jpg`.

Comment: Is `..../simulator/images/01.jpg` the filesystem location of the image?

Comment: @w3d Yes. Shouldn't it work fine as html and css are?

Comment: Yes, there shouldn't be any difference between images, HTML and CSS in this respect. Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file? Any other .htaccess files? Just to confirm, is your _CondPattern_ really `!^simulator/`?

Comment: @w3d Yes, I have double-checked, it is `!^simulator/`.

Comment: Well, that's the thing... if the _CondPattern_ is `!^simulator/` then this should not be working at all - which makes me think _something else_ is going on here. The purpose of the `RewriteCond` directive in this context is to prevent a rewrite loop, but with that pattern it is not preventing a rewrite loop. With just these directives you should be getting a 500 Internal Server Error ("Request exceeded the limit of .. internal redirects")

Comment: @w3d I believe `!^simulator/` works most likely from an apache tweak by my hosting, as they would presume most coders will screw this up anyway.

Comment: @w3d Ok, since you insist so much it should be fine for images too, it actually was. I did a syncronization with the git repo and the image issue was unrelated to the masked url.

Comment: @w3d notation "!^/some_page" works at apache2

Comment: @user2094178 you need to add slash to rewriteRule result as : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /simulator/$1 [L]

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Since this is an _internal rewrite_ you don't necessarily need to add the slash prefix to the `RewriteRule` substitution. If there is no `RewriteBase` directive to state otherwise, a relative path substitution will be relative to the directory containing the .htaccess file (the directory prefix) - which is added back at the end of processing.

Comment: @w3d If you can please post an answer stating images rewrite should be working together with html and css, so I can accept it.

Comment: I would post your "update" as an answer, you can then accept your own answer after a short period of time. (My comment about there being no difference between static images, CSS and HTML files is really just a comment.) Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to see the images due to a recent git commit that did change image paths.

As the user **w3d** pointed out in the comments that images should be working fine as well, his statement made me look to another source for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have tested rules above at my local server and edited something.

This works, I can get my jpg picture (if it exists in the `/simulator` folder) by accessing `http://example.com/picture.jpg`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/simulator
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /simulator/$1 [L]
```

Please, comparing with code below (your code). It does not work, because it results in an internal redirect loop.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^simulator/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ simulator/$1 [L]
```

The reason is in `RewriteCond`.